# iOS Swift FSCalendar Remove Event Dot From Calendar

Tags: ios, swift3, fscalendar

I'm using FSCalender in my application. I just need to remove event `dot` from calendar. For example I'm having one event of Apr 7th it will show dot on that day. But after removing all events from Apr 7th still `dot` is there, it won't disappear on that day. I have `reloaded` the calendar too. How to fix it?
[image: Not having Any Events on Apr 7th But still <code>dot</code> appears]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return 0 event for calendar,

Change like below code:

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
    return 0
}
```